# Why am I getting CORS errors from my Node ExpressJS application ONLY in Chrome?

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, cors, google-cloud-run

I have a Node app that has been working fine and setting the proper CORS headers. Yesterday I started getting CORS errors on requests from my front end to my various back end APIs. The infrastructure is hosted as Google Cloud Run containers.

I am baffled...

- CORS errors are intermittent, and some users do not get them at all
- CORS errors only present in Chrome (`Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (x86_64)`), Safari and Firefox work as expected
- I've tried:

  - Replacing the `cors` npm package/library and setting CORS headers manually (see 1, 2)
  - Deploying older versions of code that were working in the past
  - Deploying to a different platform (Heroku)

Original cors configuration:

```
    const cors = require('cors')
    const express = require('express')
    
    // snip

    const shouldCompress = (req, res) => {
      if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {
        return false;
      }
      return compression.filter(req, res);
    }

    try {

      // snip

      const app = express()
      app.use(compression({filter: shouldCompress,level:9, threshold: 0}))
      app.use(cors({ exposedHeaders: ['Content-Disposition'] }))
      app.options('*',cors())

      // ...
```

1. Manual header config:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    
        // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    
        // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
```

2. Manual config attempt:

```
app.use(cors({ exposedHeaders: ['Content-Disposition'] }))
      //app.use(cors({ exposedHeaders: ['Content-Disposition'] }))

      app.use(cors({
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true,
        exposedHeaders: ['Content-Disposition']
      }))

      app.options('*',cors())
```